# Почему не открывается файл при компиляции с помощью emcc?

Tags: c

Имеется программа на C, которая открывает простой текстовый файл, считает число байт, которые в нем содержатся, и возвращает это число:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int counter()
{
  int ch;
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("/var/www/webassembly/001/src/test.txt", "r");

  int count = 0;

  while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF)
  {
    count++;
  }

  // fclose(fp);

  return count;
}
```

Когда я компилирую этот код с помощью gcc, программа успешно работает (с добавлением функции main). Когда пытаюсь скомпилировать посредством emcc:

emcc ./src/core.c -O3 -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_counter']" -s WASM=1 -Wall -o cutter-core.js

И вызываю эту функцию в js:

```
Module.asm._couter(); // 0
```

Возвращается ноль байт. Почему?

UPD:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <emscripten.h>

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE int counter()
{
  int ch;
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("/var/www/webassembly/001/src/test.txt", "r");

  printf("errno: %s\n", strerror(errno));

  printf("file ptr: %p\n", fp);

  int count = 0;

  while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF)
  {
    count++;
  }

  // fclose(fp);

  return count;
}
```

cutter-core.js:

```
Module.asm._counter();
//cutter-core.js:1 errno: No such file or directory
//cutter-core.js:1 file ptr: 0
//0
```

Действительно не видит файл.. Я пишу относительный путь, файл гарантированно есть, но при исполнении в браузере не видит. Почему?

Comment: Выведете куда нибудь флаг открытия файла. Мб его просто открыть нельзя в браузере...

Comment: стоит проверить результат fopen и распечатать или вернуть errno, если не удалось открыть файл.

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky AndrioSkur - спасибо за отклик, обновил вопрос. получается что-то странное с путями к файлу.. =/

Comment: Если используете относительный путь - распечатайте его и cwd

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky я использовал все варианты путей, ничего не помогло. Ощущение будто такой функционал не предусмотрен просто. Никакой информации не могу найти по этой теме (

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868680/what-is-a-cross-platform-way-to-get-the-current-directory - показан юниксовый и видосовский заголовочный файл для getcwd, если в вашем компиляторе недоступен - попробуйте распечатать в вызывающем скрипте

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky Получил такой путь: "/"

Comment: Скорее всего вы получаете путь в песочнице, а файл пытаетесь открыть по полному пути *вне* её. Напишите простой цикл с `readdir()`, посмотрите, что он выведет.